# Use query results multiple times in query

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table per user which counts SO reputation for a month of a year.

```
+-----+-------+------+
| rep | month | year |
+-----+-------+------+
| 10  | 12    | 2015 |
+-----+-------+------+
| 11  | 01    | 2016 |
+-----+-------+------+
| 12  | 02    | 2016 |
+-----+-------+------+
```

Now, to display the data into a table I want the starting year, starting month, end year and end month of that user to scale the diagram accordingly.

My first idea was a sql request like this:

```
SELECT MAX(YEAR) AS maxYear,
       MAX(MONTH) AS maxMonth,
       MIN(YEAR) AS minYear,
       MIN(MONTH) AS minMonth
FROM Balance
```

But this only worked because I started in 2015 ;-). After the beginning of the new year it showed wrong results: It marked January als the first month, because the query did not look if a month was corresponding to the right year.

So I created this:

```
SELECT MAX(YEAR) AS maxYear,
       MAX(monthsOfMaxYear) AS maxMonth,
       MIN(YEAR) AS minYear,
       MIN(monthsOfMinYear) AS minMonth
FROM Balance,

  (SELECT MONTH AS monthsOfMaxYear
   FROM Balance
   WHERE YEAR =
       (SELECT MAX(YEAR)
        FROM Balance)) AS a,

  (SELECT MONTH AS monthsOfMinYear
   FROM Balance
   WHERE YEAR =
       (SELECT MIN(YEAR)
        FROM Balance)) AS b
```

But I'm not really happy with that because queries are being executed multiple times e.g. `SELECT MIN(YEAR) FROM Balance`.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: of course, if you think my whole approach isn't great, feel free to suggest another one.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(YEAR*100+MONTH) AS maxYearMonth,  MIN(YEAR*100+MONTH) AS minYearMonth FROM Balance`

Comment: in your first SELECT query need to be Group by and grouping column. For example group by username etc.

Comment: @alexIL every user has its own table, no `GROUP BY` needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: You cannot look at a month separate from its year. So combine the two starting with the year in order to get their sort order correctly: e.g. 12/2015 = 201512. This is: multiply the year by 100 and add the month. To extract the month again take its modulo 100:

```
SELECT MAX(YEAR) AS maxYear,
       MAX(YEAR * 100 + MONTH) % 100 AS maxMonth,
       MIN(YEAR) AS minYear,
       MIN(YEAR * 100 + MONTH) % 100 AS minMonth
FROM Balance
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query-

```
SELECT YEAR(MAX(CONCAT(`year`,'-',`month`,'-01'))) AS maxYear, MONTH(MAX(CONCAT(`year`,'-',`month`,'-01'))) AS maxMonth, 
       YEAR(MIN(CONCAT(`year`,'-',`month`,'-01'))) AS minYear, MONTH(MIN(CONCAT(`year`,'-',`month`,'-01'))) AS minMonth
       FROM balance;
```

You can make it better if store your year and month data in date format by below query-

```
SELECT YEAR(MAX(mydate)) AS maxYear, MONTH(MAX(mydate)) AS maxMonth, 
       YEAR(MIN(mydate)) AS minYear, MONTH(MIN(mydate)) AS minMonth
       FROM balance;
```